# Access JIRA system field value by using a script [Behaviours plugin]

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin

I have tried this using Behaviours plugin with following script..what I need is read the Sprint field value of a issue.

```
FormField sprint = getFieldByName("Sprint")
FormField productArea = getFieldByName("Product Area")
String sprintValue = (String) sprint.getValue()
if(sprintValue!= null){
productArea.setReadOnly(true)
}
```

this is what I configured in the plugin..
[image]

but hard to find any solution. I need to check this sprint field value null or not and then set a field read only..am I missing something in here? JIRA version(6.4)

Comment: this code works fine with other fields like "Team" ."Story points" but no result with the "Sprint" field

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the sprint value and see if it is null or that field is part of form etc. According to that, you should be able to change your condition to make  this work.